# How to run a django signal only once in order to affect more than one model instance

Tags: django, django-signals

Is it possible to run a django signal only once in order to affect more than one model instances?
And when this signal will run? I don't want to use crontab library.

Imagine that I have 10 instances of model A.
I want to run a signal that creates an instance of model B for every instance of model A.

Something like the below function but for all A instances:

```
@receiver(signals.post_save, sender=A) 
def create_b(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        B.objects.create()
```

Comment: Is this something you want to do only once (something like creating instances of B for already existing instances of A)? Just run a query in the shell inside a loop.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I am working in a team with different databases, so I want a change affecting all the team members, something like a custom migration which will run to all members with python manage.py migrate for instance.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a [Data Migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/migrations/#data-migrations).

First run:

```
python manage.py makemigrations --empty yourappname
```

This would generate an empty migration in your app (here yourappname), you can refer the documentation linked above to see how it would look. Now you would add your own code to the migration to do what you want. First you would add a function that would do your task for you and add it to the list `operations` by using [`RunPython`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/migration-operations/#django.db.migrations.operations.RunPython). At the end your migration should look something like:

```
from django.db import migrations

def your_function(apps, schema_editor):
    # We can't import the models directly as it may be a newer
    # version than this migration expects. We use the historical version.
    A = apps.get_model('yourappname', 'A')
    B = apps.get_model('yourappname', 'B')
    for a in A.objects.all():
        b = B.objects.create()
        # Do something with b if needed


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('yourappname', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(your_function),
    ]
```

Now anyone who runs `python manage.py migrate` would have run this command and be up to date on the changes you want them to have made.